# Finding closest number index from a vector

Tags: python, numpy

If there is a reference vector, for example:

```
ref = np.array([1., 3., 5.])
```

And a random vector:

```
r = np.array([3.1, 4.7, 0.1, 5.5])
```

Is there a fast way to find the index of the closes number in 'ref' for each number in 'r'?

Expected result is:

```
[2, 3, 1, 3]
```

3.1 is closest to 3 so the answer is index 2.

4.7 is closest to 5 so the answer is index 3.

0.1 is closest to 1 so the answer is index 1.

5.5 is closest to 5 so the answer is index 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a broadcasting:

```
np.abs(r[:,None]-ref).argmin(-1)
```

Output (remember python is 0-indexed):

```
array([1, 2, 0, 2])
```